# How to ignore files starting with numbers in Git?

Tags: git, gitignore

In a certain folder, I have image files named `foo.jpg`, `bar.png`, etc. I want to keep them in version control, except those named like `1_baz.png`, `2_zaz.jpg`, etc (since they are actually generated).

What's the entry should I add to `.gitignore`? Regex such as `[0-9]+.*` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Git does not use regexp but [glob pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) to match ignored files. Add the following line in your root `.gitignore`:

```
[0-9]*
```

If you only want to ignore those files in the `/static/img/` subdirectory you should either add the previous line to `.gitignore` file inside that subdirectory or add the following line in your root `.gitignore`:

```
/static/img/[0-9]*
```

Comment: It works if I create a `.gitignore` with this entry in that specific folder, but what about having something like `/static/img/[0-9]*` in the root `.gitignore`? How should it be, in this case?

Comment: You wrote it properly: `/static/img/[0-9]*` in the root `.gitignore` file should make files begining with a number in the static/img/ subdirectory ignored. Note: the `/` at the begining is optional. I will edit my response accordingly.