# Gitignore for folders with numbers

Tags: git, gitignore

I need an unusual gitignore rule. I want to ignore all folders, which title consists of numbers only, except for folder "1" and "88" - these two should not be ignored, as well as those, which titles contain letters.

Comment: Because that question was asked four years ago and at the time was unique. Research, especially showing that you did research, is an important part of asking a question. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore files starting with numbers in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592752/how-to-ignore-files-starting-with-numbers-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` supports [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), not regexp. If you can, you can put all these folder in another folder, ignore that folder and then force git to add the two that you want, like `git add --force folderswithnumbers/1`.